# Ajustar zoom a los límites de un LineString de MapBox en Android

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Obtengo una `LineString` de un `geojson` uso `mapbox` de motor de proyección, intento centrar a la vista la línea que se muestre en su totalidad en pantalla

en los ejemplos del SDK en JavaScript hay lo siguiente
[Fit to the bounds of a LineString](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/)

Intento hacer lo mismo pero con Java de Android, no ser como obtener los limites de un `LineString`

**Para centrar la cámara a unos limites**

Extraido de [Fit a map to a bounding box](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/fit-bound-camera/)

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
  .include(new LatLng(36.532128, -93.489121)) // Northeast
  .include(new LatLng(25.837058, -106.646234)) // Southwest
  .build();
```

Lo que necesito es obtener el `Norteast` y el `southwest` de un conjunto de coordenadas.

Las coordenadas que conforman la `LineString`

```
ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

Me falta procesar esas cordenadas para extraer los limites, `norte-este` y el `sud-oeste`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado**

Para poder calcular los limites se puede usar `LatLngBounds` se incluye los puntos que debe calcular sus limites.

En mi caso los paso todos los puntos que conforman el `LineString`

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (LatLng marker : points) {
    builder.include(marker);
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

Para ajustar la camará que quepa todo en pantalla

```
map.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0), 2000);
```

Lo que me pasa no me centra bien, el zoom de la cámara se ajusta perfectamente, pero no su centrado.

**Update**

Mapbox por defecto establece un padding superior a la `camera`, se debe usar `setPadding(...)` de [MyLocationViewSettings](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/5.0.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/widgets/MyLocationViewSettings.html#setPadding-int-int-int-int-)

```
map.getMyLocationViewSettings().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: No me atrevo a dar una respuesta ya que no estoy demasiado familiarizado con mapbox, pero leyendo la documentacion encontre `CameraPosition` ¿podria ser algo asi? `map.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(LatyLng)
                .zoom(tuZoom)
                .build());`
Como digo, no estoy nada seguro de ello, por eso prefiero dejar solo un comentario.

Comment: bueno eso seria para dar una posición en concreta, lo que me refiero es que si tienes un polígono, pues que se ajuste a la vista, el fit de toda la vida, ahora me lo hace, pero solo que no me centra bien, es como si hubiera un padding superior, seguiré investigando.

Comment: es raro entonces que al dar una posición no centre la vista, me ha picado la curiosidad con el tema, si doy con una solución comentaré.

Comment: @Israel solucionado, era el padding inicial que mapbox me ponia.

Comment: Gracias @Webserveis por comentarlo, llegue a ver algo sobre eso en Stackoverflow ingles, pero al no probarlo por mi mismo no me atreví a comentar nada ya que tambien vi algo del padding en el método easeCamera que utilizas.

Comment: Ahora que comentas eso del padding de easeCamera tal-vez pueda juntar los dos, porque tener el punto al centro, no me acaba gustar del todo.